# Trying to turn on owid-grapher's local server, I get "Waiting for MySQL to come up" forver and localhost:8080 doesn't return anything

Tags: mysql, docker, tmux

I wanted to experiment with Our World in Data's [*Grapher*](https://github.com/owid/owid-grapher/). I followed the [local development setup instructions](https://github.com/owid/owid-grapher/blob/master/docs/docker-compose-mysql.md). Most of the code worked. The Docker container is up. I can access the MySQL database with DBeaver. The docker tab in tmux says:
[image: docker tab]

```
...
db-load-data-1  | ✅ All done, grapher DB is loaded ✅
db-load-data-1 exited with code 0
```

The welcome tab correctly displays:

```
Try these url's to see if your environment is working:
    https://localhost:3030/  <-- a basic version of Our World in Data
    ...
    https://localhost:8080/wp/wp-admin/  <-- the WordPress admin interface
...
```

However, the admin tab says:

```
Waiting for MySQL to come up................................................
```

Also, the localhost websites are not responding when I try accessing them in the browser.

Has anyone here worked with owid-grapher before that can help me?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using this instead.
Python API for creating OWID data graphs: https://github.com/owid/owid-grapher-py/

- Very convenient if you are familiar with Seaborn/Plotly and Python Programming
- Minimal setup required

Comment: Although that might be a good alternative, that is not what the question was asking.